# Statistics suffered death and failed or repeated missions in Assassin's Creed 3

Tags: assassins-creed-3

Can I find statistics on the number suffered death and failed or repeated missions in Assassin's Creed 3? Whether such factors are not measured anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

While in game (in single-player while in the Animus), go to the pause menu and open the Animus Training Center.

There you can see your personal statistics in the Stats menu or see how your stats fare against your friends or the world in the Leaderboards menu.

[image]

Another option is to log on to the [Assassin's Network](https://assassinsnetwork.ubi.com) where you can keep track of your Assassin's Creed progression across all titles, participate in the community by forming clans, and fighting in events for great prizes.

Comment: @mczaplicki if you found my answer useful please vote up and accept it.

Comment: I know that. I need exactly number of suffered death or mission failed in statistics. Is such data as the number of death incurred or not successful missions are stored somewhere? Surely they do not exist in the statistics you mentioned. Is there no information on the number of death incurred or not successful missions?

Comment: If not available in Stats or ACNetwork then no. Those specific stats arenot available.

Comment: So, it's means they don't exist at all, right?

Comment: @mczaplicki Yes. What is kind of a shame. But that's what we have. If you want to accept my answer it can certainly help other people with similar questions about stats of AC 3. or previous games.